# SwiftSignalRClient error: Attempting to send data before connection has been started

Tags: swift, xcode, signalr.client

im trying to get some data using SwiftSignalRClient (https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift).
i tried the following:

```
 private let serverUrl = "https://xxxx"
 private var chatHubConnection: HubConnection
 private weak var chatHubConnectionDelegate: HubConnectionDelegate?
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 self.chatHubConnection?.delegate = ChatHubConnectionDelegate(controller: self)
        chatHubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: URL(string: serverUrl)!).withLogging(minLogLevel: .error)
            .withHttpConnectionOptions(configureHttpOptions: { (httpConnectionOptions) in
                        httpConnectionOptions.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.accessToken)"
            })
            .build()
        self.chatHubConnection?.start()
        chatHubConnection!.on(method: "ChatStart", callback: { (user: String, message: String) in
                   do {
                      print(user)
                   } catch {
                       print(error)
                   }
               })
               
        chatHubConnection!.start()
        chatHubConnection?.invoke(method: "ChatStart", ["AcceptBid": xxxx], invocationDidComplete: { (error) in
            print(error)
            
        })
```

in the first function, its not even printing neither user, nor error, while in the second function, on error printing, im getting the following error : `SwiftSignalRClient.SignalRError.invalidOperation(message: "Attempting to send data before connection has been started.`

***UPDATE***: i called the delegate function connectionDidOpen, im getting the Following error : noSupportedTransportAvailable

Comment: You should call `invoke` method on `connectionDidOpen` method of delegate. In your example you are trying invoke method before connection has been started.

Comment: well, i tried this, i got :  Creating transport failed: noSupportedTransportAvailable

Comment: So you have problem with your server. Your server should support WebSockets transportation method for this library.

Comment: Well, do you have an idea what i should tell the server guy about this?

Comment: You can send [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#advanced-http-configuration-options) link: you can say they should support `HttpTransportType.WebSockets` transport type in their SignalR configuration.

Comment: Well, WebSockets are enabled on the server, could it be a problem from somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea anymore. `noSupportedTransportAvailable` means that your server doesn't support `WebSocket`. But if it is, I can't think of any different suggestions.

Comment: FWIW longpolling transport is also now supported.